# Overriding system.diagnostics in a subdirectory web.config

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, web-config, system.diagnostics

I am attempting to enable WCF message tracing for a single service (one of several included in this IIS application).  I have created a web.config file that is placed in the same physical directory as my .svc file.  I am able to configure the service from this web.config file, modifying behaviors, endpoints etc.  However, when I attempt to include the include a system.diagnostics node, it appears to have no effect.  This does not produce a trace file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>    
        <services>
            <service name="My.Awesome.Wcf.Service" />
            <!-- my endpoints and behaviors are defined programmatically -->
        </services>

        <diagnostics>
            <messageLogging
                 logEntireMessage="true"
                 logMalformedMessages="true"
                 logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                 logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                 maxMessagesToLog="3000" />
        </diagnostics>
    </system.serviceModel>

    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true" >
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="xml"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                       initializeData="C:\logs\Traces.svclog" />
        </sharedListeners>
        <trace autoflush="true" />
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

If I move the entire system.diagnostics node out of this sub-directory web.config to the application's root web.config, then it magically starts working.  As far as I can tell, the system.diagnostics section is not limited to the application's root web.config, since my machine.config shows this section definition:

```xml
<section name="system.diagnostics" type="System.Diagnostics.SystemDiagnosticsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

Note that this definition does not include an "allowDefinition" attribute, which, according to this [MSDN documentation for the section element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228245.aspx) means that it can be defined "Everywhere" which should include physical subdirectories.  I have not been able to find any system.diagnostics definitions in any parent web.configs either.

Does anyone know why this system.diagnostics configuration might not be getting processed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close out this question: the real question is why would you want to specify WCF logging at a sub-folder level?

WCF hosting is at the IIS Application level. You can't have WCF logging disabled for services at the root URL then enabled at lower levels. If you want to emulate such scenario, then you need 2 WCF applications, one within the other (in IIS); in .NET, they are 2 separate AppDomains.

If you prefer to stick to one AppDomain, then you can perhaps achieve what you are trying to accomplish to by creating message filters. See "Message Filters" in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\temp\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response.  This didn't work, though, the log file is still not being generated.

Comment: Maybe check the rights on the target folder where the log should be created? give everybody write rights for a starter?

Comment: Yes it exists and I added full access rights to "Everyone".  The file is created in that directory no problem when I put the system.diagnostics node in the application root web config instead of the child directory, so I know the IIS identity can write to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Does C:\logs\ exist?  If it doesn't, the log file will not get created at all.

Comment: See my comment to Nick below.  When the system.diagnostics node is in the root application web.config (instead of the one in the subdirectory) the file is created just fine, so I know IIS can write to the directory.

Comment: Yes, I see.  You say the file is created fine.  Is it empty?  WCF does not write the entries right away; sometimes there is a delay.  You can cause an immediate write by recycling the app pool.

Comment: It only works if I move the system.diagnostics node into the application root web.config, this is not acceptable for my particular application.  I'm not really concerned with making it work in that configuration, since it's not an option for me.  That said, I do see valid log data when it is configured like that.  I'm more curious why I cannot put the declaration in the web.config that is in the subdirectory.

Comment: Got it.  Well the real question is why would you want to specify WCF logging at a sub-folder level?  WCF hosting is at the IIS Application level anyway.  You can't have WCF logging disabled for services at the root URL then enabled at lower levels.
If you want to emulate such scenario, then you need 2 WCF applications, one within the other (in IIS); in .NET, they are 2 separate AppDomains.
Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, another way of achieving what you want is by creating message filters.  See "Message Filters" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx.

Comment: Well, you may have answered my question.  I did not realize that the logging was enabled or disabled at the app domain level.  Message filters are probably the answer.  At the same time, it pains me a little to clutter up the common root web.config with this highly service specific logic.  Seems like it **should** be able to be declared at the sub-folder level.

Comment: @Philippe let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2341/discussion-between-gabe-and-philippe)